# tslint: Is there a way to disable prefer-const within a loop?

Tags: typescript, tslint

`tslint` 5.11 just made the following `let` to `const` conversion:

```
for (let i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; ++i) {
  let column = array[i];
```

to

```
for (let i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; ++i) {
  const column = array[i];
```

but (while likely innocuous) in my opinion this change is wrong!  (Because it is unnecessary and misleading.)

Is there a way to disable the `let` to `const` conversion within loops? 
And while I could disable `prefer-const` on case by case basis using [rule flags](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/rule-flags/), I'd rather not pollute my code with those comments.  Ideally, I'd be able fix this with a setting within `tslint.json`.

Comment: Can you provide additional code? What is `column` used for in the subsequent lines of code?

Comment: It shouldn't matter - the code is meant to be generic.  Instead of column we can call it `elem` maybe (for Array element, not necessarily DOM element)

Comment: Okay. As far is I know `let` is by far more memory consuming than `const`. And as long as you do not reassign `column` in the subsequent code, it is recommended to use const instead of let. Here is how you can stop it: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/prefer-const/

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; the `prefer-const` setting is how I would disable `let` to `const` conversion altogether, but I'm hoping to only disable it within loops.  Is that not possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find any more granular switch than this. I guess it's currently not possible to tell those cases apart. Either you do it entirely or not at all. Sorry.

Comment: How is it misleading? Just out of curiosity. Also maybe for (const column of array) or for (const [i, column] of array.entries()) is cleaner and less misleading?

Answer (score 0):

ATTOW it appears that disabling `let` to `const` conversion within a loop is not possible using tslint's `prefer-const` (or any other config setting).
(A big thanks to @Lynx242 for your investigation and insight!)

What I ended up doing was moving my variable declaration outside of the body of the loop itself:

```
for (let i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; ++i) {
  const column = array[i];
```

and into the for loop's init block:

```
for (let i = 0, len = array.length, column; i < len; ++i) {
  column = array[i];
```

Here we are not redeclaring `column` with each iteration of the loop; while a perhaps minor performance improvement, IMHO, this code feels much cleaner and less confusing.